# Upgrade 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS

Tags: format

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu version 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS .

Is there a way that I can install it with fresh copy and a formatted partition ???

I don't want my other drives to get formatted. But just the drive that contains file system.

Comment: do you have any other os in your machine

Comment: I just have 12.04 Lts... no any other OS

Answer (score 1):

**How To Do a Fresh Install of Ubuntu to a Specific Drive or Partition**

- When installing Ubuntu 14.04, at the installation type menu, you need
  to select the bottom option **'Something Else'** instead of 'Erase
  everything and Install Ubuntu'.

This will bring you to the partitioning menu where you select the drive & partition for installation.

Your Primary hard drive will be listed as 'Sda' followed by any partitions that are on it like Sda1 or Sda2. Other drives will be listed below as 'Sdb' 'Sdc' and so on.

- Click on  the partition on the drive you want to install to and
  select '**change**'.
- You need to select '**use this partition as Ext4 File System**'.
- Then you need to set the '**mount point**' as '**/**' which is the
  root file system and click OK.

You can also select '**format partition**' at this point.

You will be taken back to the previous menu and that partition will have a tick next to it.

Make sure no other partitions or drives have ticks by them and proceed with the installation. Only the drive / partitions you have selected will be used.

Note: You can also format the partition using 'Disks' or 'Gparted' from a live session, by selecting 'Try Ubuntu' on the installation disc/usb.