# Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I am new to Ubuntu and have a 12.04 operating system. I want to upgrade to 14.04. Can I do this? Also if I can will this replace the 12.04 or will both 12.04 and 14.04 be on here.

Comment: If you want to upgrade 12.04 to 14.04, you'll have to upgrade to each intermediate version, or if you get an error look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release). If you want to have both 12.04 and 14.04 at the same time, create Live Media for 14.404 and look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/501189/upgrade-12-04-lts-to-14-04-lts).

Comment: @Theschwa that's not true. You can upgrade directly between 12.04 to 14.04 (LTS to LTS).

Comment: @Alvar Didn't know that. That's never happened for me before...maybe I just have a setting wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can upgrade 12.04 to 14.04. Using the Update Manager, you can replace the current installation (12.04) with 14.04. The upgrade process will preserve your personal files and documents. You can start the upgrade process by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

The Update Manager will search for available upgrades then prompt you to upgrade. Follow the on-screen prompts until the upgrade process begins. The upgrade process will take several minutes. When it has finished, you will be asked to restart the computer to complete the upgrade.

Comment: ok I'm grateful for the help. I had downloaded the 14.04 from the ubuntu website just hadn't went any further didn't want to mess anything up. lol Next question (from someone who knows nothing about computers) is the terminal just another word for the start page?

Comment: No; in simplest terms the terminal is a way to type commands to the  computer. The "start page" could be many things, perhaps you should open a new question and ask. Don't forget to mark this question as answered if you found an solution to your question.      http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers